# How to decrease indent level in Spotless?

Tags: java, gradle, spotless

I'm using the following in my `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
  id 'com.diffplug.gradle.spotless' version '4.5.1'
}

spotless {
  java {
    googleJavaFormat()

    replaceRegex 'Combine function with lambda.', '(\\.[A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z]+\\()\\n\\s+', '$1'
  }
```

This reformats the following code:

```
.flatMap(
    t2 -> {
      …
    }));
```

to:

```
.flatMap(t2 -> {
      …
    }));
```

What needs to be done so the indent level is decreased such that it reformats to:

```
.flatMap(t2 -> {
  …
}));
```